# How to change fileupload name

Tags: asp.net

im using following code to upload

```
protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(FileUploadControl.HasFile)
  {
    try
    {
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
        FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~upload/") + filename);
        StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
    }
  }
}
```

I want to change the upload file name...I have to assign file name for every uploaded file how?

Answer (score 5):

This line pickes up the the name of the uploaded file:

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
```

This line tells the server what to save the file as:

```
 FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);
```

Simply change the value of `filename` to something else before saving.

Comment: I want to change uploaded file name not in Server path storage name

Comment: for every upload file i have to declare the name

Comment: @Domnic - You can't change the `FileUploadControl.FileName`. It is what comes from the browser and the computer that is uploading the file.

Answer (score 1):

there is a way to change the name of the file that we downloaded to our "~Server/Userfolder"(as an example)..

i was really thinking on renaming file before the .SaveAs command, which is gonna be like:

```
if (Request.Files != null)
{
    var getmyfile = Request.Files["some_photo"];
    try
    {
        if (getmyfile.FileName != "" && getmyfile.FileName != null && getmyfile.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            ///Create Useruploads path.
            var path = Server.MapPath("~/Useruploads" + "\\");

            ///Get file info that we gonna upload to server..
            FileInfo TheFile = new FileInfo(path + Path.GetFileName(getmyfile.FileName));
            ///Note: i used Path.GetFileName(getmyfile.FileName) code cause getmyfile.FileName gives full path of that file..
            if (TheFile.Exists)
            {
                ///Seperate file name and extention..
                var fname = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(TheFile.Name);
                var ext = TheFile.Extension;
                var path2 = path + fname;

                ///As long as we got file names, same as in server..
                while(new FileInfo(path2+ext).Exists)
                {
                ///Add "-img" to its name..
                    path2 = path2 + "-img";
                }

                FileInfo ccc = new FileInfo(path2 + ext);
                string f_art = ccc.Name.Replace(" ", "");///Clean space.. (Optional)

                getmyfile.SaveAs(f_art);
                somedb.some_photo = Path.GetFileName(f_art); ///Its not fart its file art lol!

            }
            else  ///if file is not exist in our server..
            {
                var path3 = (path + Path.GetFileName(getmyfile.FileName));

                FileInfo ccc = new FileInfo(path3);
                string f_art = ccc.Name.Replace(" ", "");

                getmyfile.SaveAs(f_art);
                some.some_photo = Path.GetFileName(f_art);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
    {
    form.Set("lblStatus",ex.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    form.Set("lblStatus", ex.Message);
    }

    db.somedbs.InsertOnSubmit(somedb);
    db.SubmitChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

(Optional) Also u can use :

```
var f_art = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(TheFile.Name), "[^a-zA-Z]", "");
```

instead of using .Replace(" ",""); but at this it just cleans spaced areas and if u use the code up there its gonna clean everything except A to Z , a to z characters which means no numbers will be applied to that name nor space or other characters which are not between A and Z..